# ¿Como mostrar la imagen que acabo de seleccionar en un formulario? (input type='file')

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que el usuario pueda ver la imagen que ha seleccionado. Lo que se me ocurre es recoger el nombre del archivo y luego colocarlo en el atributo `src` de una imagen, todo con Javascript pero tengo entendido que ese nombre del archivo no se puede capturar por motivos de seguridad. Entonces como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Por favor publica tu código HTML y lo que hayas intentado de JS. Dale un vistazo a este link para saber como formular una buen pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pesar de que la pregunta está un poco mal formulada, te dejo la respuesta para tu cuestionamiento. Basta con añadir una etiqueta `img` que cambiaremos con el contenido de la imagen una vez cargada, para ello utilizaremos **JQuery**, pero también podría hacerse con **JS** Puro.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) { //Revisamos que el input tenga contenido
    var reader = new FileReader(); //Leemos el contenido
    
    reader.onload = function(e) { //Al cargar el contenido lo pasamos como atributo de la imagen de arriba
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() { //Cuando el input cambie (se cargue un nuevo archivo) se va a ejecutar de nuevo el cambio de imagen y se verá reflejado.
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" /> <br> 
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="Imagen" />
</form>
```